# Use protected static function of the base class from the friend of the derived class

Tags: c++, clang

Different compiler seems to have different opinion on the subject. The following code compiles fine with `gcc`, but fails with `clang`:

```
class Base {
protected:
    static void f() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
    friend class DerivedFriend;
};

class DerivedFriend {
public:
    void g() {
        Base::f();
    }
};
```

`clang`'s error is:

```
main.cpp:13:15: error: 'f' is a protected member of 'Base'
        Base::f();
              ^
main.cpp:3:17: note: declared protected here
    static void f() {}
                ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491000/friend-class-inherited-classes-are-not-friend-as-well

Comment: @BlakeMcConnell I don't think so. In the question you are pointing to, "friend arrow" has a different direction: class hierarchy is a friend of a single class.

Comment: agreed, but have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878723/does-a-friend-see-base-classes

Comment: @BlakeMcConnell yes, this looks similar, but we wouldn't see T.C.'s exhaustive answer if I'd find this question before posting mine :)

Comment: @BlakeMcConnell That one's for non-static members, for which there is an extra rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [CWG issue 1873](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1873), which changed the rules for this case ([class.access.base]/p5):

> A member `m` is accessible at the point `R` when named in class `N` if
>
> - [...]
> - `m` as a member of `N` is protected, and `R` occurs in a member or friend of class `N`, or in a member **<s>or friend</s>** of a class `P` derived
>     from `N`, where `m` as a member of `P` is public, private, or protected,
>     or
> - [...]

Here, `N` is `Base`, `P` is `Derived`, `m` is `f()`, and `R` occurs in a member of `DerivedFriend`; pre-CWG1873 this would be allowed, but CWG1873 removed the "friend of a derived class" case and makes this ill-formed.

The fix is to refer to `f` as a member of `Derived` rather than `Base`.

Comment: @anxieux It was reported by a Clang dev, so I'm not surprised.